# Java Big Integer - Nested get

Tags: java, get, nested, biginteger

I'm having trouble working with `BigInteger` class. I had a input list with just normal `int`s, but I had to change the said to list to accept Big Integers as well.

In multiple parts of my code I have instructions like this one:

```
input.set(input.get(i + 3), 
        (input.get(input.get(i + 1)) + input.get(input.get(i + 2))));
```

And they produce errors like this one:

```
Cannot convert type of expression  
    (input.get(input.get(i + 1)) + input.get(input.get(i + 2))) from int to E
```

I have tried doing something like this:

```
(input.get(BigInteger.valueOf(input.get(i + 1)))
    .add(BigInteger.valueOf(input.get(BigInteger(input.get(i + 2)))))));
```

But that hasn't helped.

Comment: what is `input`?

Comment: Blindly converting everything into a `BigInt` is unlikely to help. Think about what each part of that is and what it represents. Then convert only the actual `BigInt`s.

Comment: Input is a List<BigInteger> @YCF_L

Comment: @JohnC, `List` doesn't have a `get(BigInteger)` method.

Comment: What you are trying to do with your code?

Comment: @YCF_L I have a input file of numbers (both normal and big integers). I'm looking for a good way to store them somewhere so I can easily iterate over them and get values from indexes that I have. In my original post, the example that I gave was that I had to replace a number at a `(i+3)` position with a value from `(i + 1) + (i + 2)` index.

Comment: @JohnC was it really meant to be nested `get()` calls? From your comment it looks like you simply want to sum + replace certain elements which doesn't require nested calls.

Comment: @Amongalen Sorry, perhaps I worded my comment wrong. If have a list of numbers: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` and my current iteration is `i = 3`, I have to be able to get the value that's at the index of `i + 1` value. So, in this case `i + 1 would be 4` and I'd have to get `5` back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own method taking a `List<BigInteger>` to be searched and a `String` value to be found, because there is the constructor `new BigInteger(String value)`. You could find the value by streaming the list:

```
public static BigInteger findIn(List<BigInteger> source, String value) {
    return source.stream()
            .filter(bi -> bi.equals(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(value))))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

This assumes that the values to be searched for are converted into `Strings` beforehand.

**Why `String`s?**

That is already explained in the answer given by @Amongalen:
*(..) `BigInteger` can store much bigger numbers than can be represented with `int`.*
Which means you may have to pass a value that is not storable in an `int` variable.

You can use it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide some sample data
    List<BigInteger> bigInts = new ArrayList<>();
    bigInts.add(new BigInteger("123456789101112"));
    bigInts.add(new BigInteger("123456789101113"));
    bigInts.add(new BigInteger("123456789101114"));
    bigInts.add(new BigInteger("123456789101115"));
    bigInts.add(new BigInteger("54"));

    // provide a variable for the expression
    int i = 51;
    // convert your expression to String
    BigInteger n = findIn(bigInts, String.valueOf(3 + i));

    System.out.println(n.toString());
}
```

The output is just `54`.

**Please note that you cannot simply `add` a value to an existing `BigInteger` and expect it to change, because an arithmetical operation does not alter an existing instance but returns a new one:**

> From [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)):

```
public BigInteger add(BigInteger val)
```

> Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this + val).

**Conclusion**
You have to
  (1) find the value in the list,
  (2) perform the arithmetical operation and store the return value,
  (3) remove the old value from the list and
  (4) add the new one.

Comment: OP is looking for something to be able to nest `.get` calls. Perhaps you could show how it works because it isn't obvious.

Comment: @Amongalen I explained a little more, there is no possibility of adding a `BigInteger` to another one that's in a `List` directly. You have to swap the values because an addition returns a new instance instead of changing an existing one.

Comment: @deHaar Thank you for the comprehensive explanation.  I have decided of using a different data structure instead, but your explanation of what was going on was superb.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for this to work. You're trying to call `List.get(int)` and pass `BigInteger` (which you get from calling `input.get(i + 1)`) as a paramether. As `BigInteger` can store much bigger numbers than can be represented with `int`, it is not possible to convert one to the other.

You will have to rethink your data structures and what you want to do with them.